# what does (node *) NULL mean in C?

Tags: c, pointers, linked-list

I was going through a book studying Linked list and saw these lines

```
if( *head == NULL){

}else if ( (*head)->next == (node *) NULL ){

}
```

what is the difference between `NULL` and `(node *) NULL` can they be used interchangeably?

```
typedef struct nodeType{
    int info;
    struct nodeType *next;
}node;
```

Comment: It means the author of the code doesn't know what he's doing.  `NULL` does not need a cast.

Comment: This is just obfuscation. Pointers don't need comparison to `NULL` in conditionals. `if(*head) ` and `if ((*head)->next)` would do perfectly.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

When comparing pointers, types are not considered, so it is pointless.

The author likely just included it for clarity if it's an introductory book.  If it's not an introductory book, then the author either has an odd coding style, or somehow thinks that it's more meaningful.

Comment: @Supr Pointless is just my go to word for useless :)

Answer (score 7):

They can be used interchangeably. But it is non-standard and unusual to typecast `NULL` as your code does.

No cast is required.